# How to get the name of an object property in powershell?

Tags: object, powershell, properties

I know I can use get-member to get all the properties of an object but I'm going through a list of objects and I'm interested in the very last property whose name keeps changing. To automate my script, I'm trying to get the name of that last property but I'm not sure how.

Let's say I have:

```
$result | get-member

Name        MemberType     Definition
----        ----------     ----------
something   something      something
.
.
.
myProperty NoteProperty   System.Object[]
```

"myProperty" changes with every different $result.

So does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try:

```
( $result | get-member)[-1]
```

Comment: I needed that! Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

You can also try this to get all of the property names

```
foreach ($property in $result.PSObject.Properties) { $property.Name  }
```

Comment: Could I possibly filter that to find out the unknown name of the last property?