# Trying to Access Properties of PSObject class

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to write a program that gets a list of open files on a file server and lists them to a ListView. I am able to get back a collection of the files that are currently open but I can't get to the properties I need.

How can I access these properties?

I have a couple pictures here that will hopefully help.

https://onedrive.live.com/?id=22875E7FE09C494%2126144&cid=022875E7FE09C494&group=0

Answer (score 1):

To list properties

```
$file = Get-Item 'c:\file.txt'
$file.GetType().GetProperties()
```

or @stanley-de-boer in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838837/how-to-get-the-name-of-an-object-property-in-powershell)

```
foreach ($property in $result.PSObject.Properties) { $property.Name  }
```

to list values

```
foreach ($property in $result.PSObject.Properties) { $property.value }
```

To list the functions

```
Get-Member $file
```